# Cannot log java.sql.SQLException in a Log4j Spring desktop application

Tags: java, spring, log4j

Hi guys Im using log4j on a desktop Spring Application.  I am having difficulty logging the exception on my logfile whenever I deliberately use an invalid username/password for my Database Connection. I cant get to log the exception : *java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied*

Below is the Stacktrace and my log4j.properties

**LOG4J PROPERTIES**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout, ERROR

# Application logging options
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG    
log4j.logger.jdbc.resultset=ERROR
log4j.logger.jdbc.connection=ALL
log4j.logger.jdbc.resultsettable=OFF

log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=ERROR
log4j.logger.java.sql.SQLException=ALL

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\myapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**STACK TRACE**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon
>   denied

```
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:240)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
at com.pldt.financials.service.AccountReceivableService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3a1d2243.generateUploadFile(<generated>)
at com.pldt.core.App.start(App.java:33)
at com.pldt.core.App.main(App.java:19)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:792)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:364)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:202)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to lay in the fact that the exception is happening in the AOP transaction object.  Since AOP works by creating a proxy object, the exception is being thrown there rather than where you are attempting to catch the exception.  I believe there is an AOP annotation though for catching exceptions, but I can only think of the @Around annotation at the moment.

I've only just learned basic AOP myself, but here is a good summary of the annotations available including the one to trap thrown exceptions:

```
@Aspect
public class AfterThrowingExample {

  @AfterThrowing("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation()")
  public void doRecoveryActions() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

From:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not log SQL exceptions. Instead it just wraps them in a corresponding DataAccessException and throws further. It is the responsibility of your application to catch and handle (e.g. log) runtime exceptions. In order to avoid catches all over your code, you should do it as high in the call stack as possible.